# Merging two "(document).ready(function()"s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two jquery/javascript codes but I couldn't merge them. Everytime one of the functions was disable. How can I merge the codes. Please help me, thanks.

First file:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function(){ 
 jQuery('ul.menu-primary').superfish({ 
 animation: {opacity:'show'},
autoArrows:  true,
     dropShadows: false, 
     speed: 200,
     delay: 800
     });
 });

jQuery(function(){ 
 jQuery('ul.menu-secondary').superfish({ 
 animation: {opacity:'show'},
autoArrows:  true,
     dropShadows: false, 
     speed: 200,
     delay: 800
     });
 });

//first ready function
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('.fp-slides').cycle({
  fx: 'scrollHorz',
  timeout: 4000,
  delay: 0,
  speed: 400,
  next: '.fp-next',
  prev: '.fp-prev',
  pager: '.fp-pager',
  continuous: 0,
  sync: 1,
  pause: 1,
  pauseOnPagerHover: 1,
  cleartype: true,
  cleartypeNoBg: true
 });
 });
```

second file:

```
function checkCopyRight(/*string*/url){
    var copyrightLinks = $("a[href='" + url + "']");
    return copyrightLinks.length > 0;
}
// second ready function
$().ready(function(){
    if(!(checkCopyRight("http://e1.com")&&
         checkCopyRight("http://e2.com")&&
         checkCopyRight("http://e3.com"))){
        alert("...");
    }
});
```

I get a "Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly." message. There any character limit?

Comment: Yes, so I passed the character limit test. Sorry for the question..

Comment: You actually have 4 ready functions here. 3 in the first, and 1 in the second.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() {  and jQuery(function() are both the same... The later is just a alias of the former .. So a total of 4 in both the blocks of code

Comment: lol, you cant call doc ready twice!

Comment: Also, `$(function(){ ` is the exact same as `$(document).ready(`

Comment: can anyone tell me what are the possible values for "fx" please...!!!???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have **3** Ready functions and one *wannabe* ready function. I've rewritten your code as it should be in one ready call. Give it a try:

```
function checkCopyRight(/*string*/url){
    var copyrightLinks = jQuery("a[href='" + url + "']");
    return copyrightLinks.length > 0;
}

jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.menu-primary').superfish({ 
        animation: {opacity:'show'},
        autoArrows:  true,
        dropShadows: false, 
        speed: 200,
        delay: 800
    });

    jQuery('.menu-secondary').superfish({ 
        animation: {opacity:'show'},
        autoArrows:  true,
        dropShadows: false, 
        speed: 200,
        delay: 800
    });

    jQuery('.fp-slides').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',
        timeout: 4000,
        delay: 0,
        speed: 400,
        next: '.fp-next',
        prev: '.fp-prev',
        pager: '.fp-pager',
        continuous: 0,
        sync: 1,
        pause: 1,
        pauseOnPagerHover: 1,
        cleartype: true,
        cleartypeNoBg: true
    });

    if(!(checkCopyRight("http://e1.com") && checkCopyRight("http://e2.com") && checkCopyRight("http://e3.com"))) {
        alert("...");
    }
})
```

- $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended) [[1]](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Also, keep in mind, You dont really need `noConflict` unless you are using another JavaScript Library like MooTools or Prototype. A Plugin like Superfish is not relly a reason to call no Conflict. If there is no conflict, you can use `$` as shorthand for jQuery instead of constantly rewriting jQuery.

$(document).ready is the same as JavaScript's .load function and since jQuery 1.0 you can use the shorthand version `jQuery(function() { /* do work */ })` or `$(function() { /* do work */ })`

For more information:

- [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) (also info on noConflict)
- [.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) (API Page)
- [My Blog on using jQuery](http://spyk3lc.blogspot.com/2012/11/preliminary-will-be-edited-this-weekend.html) (needs work, hoping to edit it this weekend, sorry)

Comment: I think, I was try same things but your codes run correctly.  You have magical hands :) Your answer is perfect for the beginners like me. Thanks for your great helps.

Comment: Glad I could be of help, honestly I was worried i didnt' provide enough info as I'm at work and dont have but short burst of times for this, lol.

Comment: :) Thanks a lot, you are better than Javascript for Dummies book :)

Comment: @XeeMezAsHu I honestly don't know for sure as I've used neither of those plugins. I simply answered why this code was laid out wrong. The plugin options I *think* you're referring too can be found [**here**](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/options.html). It looks like you can use all your traditional *fx names*. Maybe have a look at [**jQuery Effects**](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/), as I think the plugin writer simply used those basic methods to run the effects.

Comment: @XeeMezAsHu Also, lol, on the [**main page**](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) I think those are the actual *fx* names used in plugin

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.fp-slides').cycle({
      fx: 'scrollHorz',
      timeout: 4000,
      delay: 0,
      speed: 400,
      next: '.fp-next',
      prev: '.fp-prev',
      pager: '.fp-pager',
      continuous: 0,
      sync: 1,
      pause: 1,
      pauseOnPagerHover: 1,
      cleartype: true,
      cleartypeNoBg: true
   });

   if(!(checkCopyRight("http://e1.com")&&
      checkCopyRight("http://e2.com")&&
      checkCopyRight("http://e3.com"))){
      alert("...");
   }
});
```

You need to import the second file first since the first file uses a function inside second file.

Comment: Thanks for your great answers. I think all answers are perfect but SpYk3HH's was more easier to use for me. So, I choose him answer. Thanks again for your great helps Mauricio Giordano.